# Calling the Web API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following errors:

[image: Screenshot of the error.]

I am able to search from my `.json` file with the name but I would like to search same time with ID as well. I went through jQuery Traversing Methods from w3schools but I could not find the answer that I am looking for.

My second problem is that I have used a jQuery autocomplete plugin, but it does not seems to be working on my content. What is that I am missing? And What should I focus on?

Here is the my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Kunde</title>

    <script src="autocomplete/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
    <link href="autocomplete/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>ToolBox Search</h2>
            <h3>Search by ID or NAME </h3>
            <input type="text" id="KUNDE" size="50" />              
            <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
        </div>
        <ul></ul>
        <div class="footer"><p> © Copyright 2016</p> <strong><a href="http://rackpeople.com/">RackPeople</a></strong>.</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var uri = 'json.json';
        function find() {
            var info = $('#KUNDE').val();
            $.getJSON(uri).done(function (data) {
                var item = data.filter(function (obj) {
                    return obj.name === info;
                })[0];

                if (typeof item !== 'undefined' || item !== null) {
                    $("ul").append("<li>" + 'ID      = ' + item.ID, 'Name    = ' + item.name, "<br />" + 'Phone      = ' + item.phone, "<br />" + 'Contact       = ' + item.contact, "<br />" + 'BalanceLCY      = ' + item.balanceLCY, "<br />" + 'CreditLimitLCY       = ' + item.creditLimitLCY, "</li>")
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#RESULTS').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
        }

        var options = {
            url: "json.json",    
            getValue: "name",    
            list: {
                match: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },    
            theme: "square"
        };

        $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options);    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the AJAX request working? Have you checked the console for errors? What is the content of the `json.json` file?

Comment: Also, your autocomplete library isn't work as you include it in the page before you add jquery. Always add jquery.js first.

Comment: Hi Rory I am going to add jquery.js in first place. It ' s seems my Ajax working fine . I took a screen shot and added to top of this page.Thank you.

Comment: As I mentioned - those errors are because you include your scripts in the wrong order. Include `jquery-2.0.3.min.js` ***before*** `jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js`.

Comment: Wauww Rory my autocomplete working now :) Do you have any succession for my first question as well?